# Using core/model database with small changes on different installations for customization without duplicating code

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sql-data-tools

As an example core database looks like this:

```
Person  - Id, FirstName, LastName
Address - Id, Street, ZipCode
```

This model is used on the majority of the installations but for a couple of installations I want to add customized columns, let's say the column `State` to `Address` for Customer X and `BirthDate` to `Person` for Customer Y.

Now, I don't want to add these columns to the core database because the `State` column is only used by our US customers and the `BirthDate` is only used by our European customers were `BirthDate` is obligatory (`NOT NULL`) and would therefore need a dummy value for all the other customers.

I was checking in GitHub about having several branches - `Core` and `US-Customer` - but that would mean that the whole `Core` solution would be copied over to the `US-Customer` branch but when the `Core` branch is changed it would not update the `US-Customer` branch i.e. having to maintain basically two repositories.

Is it possible to have this sort of customization either in `SQL Data Tools` or in `GitHub` were the customized solutions (e.g. `US-Customer`) would only have the absolutely necessary changes and without `SQL Data Tools` throwing errors in `Visual Studio` about missing tables or any other error?

Example:

`Core` branch

```
Person  - Id, FirstName, LastName
Address - Id, Street, ZipCode
```

`US-Customer` branch

```
ALTER TABLE Address ADD State CHAR(2) NOT NULL
```

`EU-Customer` branch

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD BirthDate DATE NOT NULL
```

Comment: I just want to confirm, are you using `sql-server-data-tools` - SSDT extension for Visual Studio and you have created SQL Database project there?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev From Visual Studio I create a new project from the template "SQL Server Database Project" which is part of SSDT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

There is no very easy way of implementing so. If you wish to do that completely in SSDT way, then you need to create several projects:

- ProjectCore --> will have all shared objects. It shouldn't have references to the projects below;
- ProjectUS --> will have all the objects for US and reference `ProjectCore` as `The same database`;
- ProjectEU --> will have all the objects for EU and reference `ProjectCore` as `The same database`.

Both `ProjectUS` and `ProjectEU` will have their own publish profiles. You'll have put full definition of different objects there, not just ALTER statements.

Comment: Then I would have the shared code from `ProjectCore` in `ProjectUS` and `ProjectEU` which doesn't seem to bring any benefit and additionality add another repository to maintain. Right?

Comment: It will include all the code only when you publish, physically there won't be any files in there. The `ProjectCore` won't be used for publishing anywhere. No extra repository is needed for that, if you are talking about source control repository